# Select character of two column which is less than 10

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want only those records which is having length of `firstname+ lastname` less than 10 from the table below

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( id, firstname, lastname ) AS
SELECT 1, 'ravi',         'kamble' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'pravinkumar',  'kamble' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'sunil',        'dev'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'rahul',        'k'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'abhijit',      's'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'kapil',        'dev'    FROM DUAL
```

Output

```
ID   firstname  lastname
3    sunil      dev     (8) 
4    rahul      k       (6) 
5    abhijit    s       (8) 
6    kapil      dev     (8)
```

So this ouput does not contain record 1 and 2 because of length of this record having equal to or more than 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName FROM TABLE
WHERE LENGTH(CONCAT(FirstName,LastName)) < 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  LENGTH( firstname ) + LENGTH( lastname ) < 10
```

**Output**:

```
ID | FIRSTNAME | LASTNAME
-: | :-------- | :-------
 3 | sunil     | dev     
 4 | rahul     | k       
 5 | abhijit   | s       
 6 | kapil     | dev
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b7082ccab538d4a5547ab20b39423b80)*